# How do I migrate shotwell tags to clean installation?

Tags: installation, shotwell, migration

I have Shotwell installed in 11.10.  When 12.04 comes out I will do a clean install as usual but I would like to not have to redo all those tags.  Is that possible and if so how?

Answer (score 5):

Two ways of doing this, depending on one particular setting in the options:

[image: Shotwell prefs]

If you **do have** this box checked, all the tags are already in the photos. Just backup and restore to the new install.

If you  **do not** have this checked, just copy your .shotwell folder from your home directory (press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files), and then copy it to the new install. For shotwell 0.13.0 or later, instead copy ~/.local/share/shotwell

Comment: @dan-carter Thanks for the helpful edit, I've manually overridden the earlier [rejections by other users](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/728156) which were clearly a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you back up your ~/home folder. Shotwell as with the rest of the applications, keep there settings in your home folder.

To back up shotwell settings. Copy or move `~/.shotwell` to another partition or drive.

Example: `sudo mv ~/.shotwell    /dev/sdc1/backup/shotwell`

this moves `<sudo mv>` the folder  `~/home/.shotwell`  `/device/USB/backup folder`